# SQL Server - recursively calculated column

Tags: sql-server

I need to calculate a column based of a seed row where each row's value uses the "previous" row's values. I feel like this should be a recursive query but I can't quite wrap my head around it.

To illustrate:

```
BOP     EOP     IN     OUT     Wk_Num
--------------------------------------
6       4       10     12      1
?       ?       2      6       2
?       ?       7      5       3
...     ...     ...    ...     ...
```

So the next row's BOP and EOP columns need to be calculated using the seed row. The IN and OUT values are already present in the table.

BOP = (previous row's EOP)

EOP = (Previous row's EOP) + IN - OUT  [where IN and OUT are from the current row)

OUTPUT of this example should look like:

```
BOP     EOP     IN     OUT     Wk_num
-------------------------------------
6       4       10     12      1
4       0       2      6       2
0       2       7      5       3
2       6       4      0       4
...     ...     ...    ...     ...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a Recursive CTE for this;

```
WITH RecursiveCTE AS (
  -- Base Case
  SELECT
    BOP,
    EOP,
    [IN],
    [OUT],
    [WK_Num]
  FROM [someTable]
  WHERE BOP IS NOT NULL

  UNION ALL

  SELECT
      r.EOP AS BOP,
      r.EOP + r2.[In] - r2.[Out] AS EOP,
      r2.[IN],
      r2.[OUT],
      r2.[WK_Num]
  FROM [someTable] r2
  INNER JOIN [RecursiveCTE] r
     ON r2.[Wk_Num] = r.[Wk_Num] + 1
)
SELECT * FROM RecursiveCTE
```

Here is a SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e041f/1

You basically define the base case as the first row (by saying the row with BOP != null), then join to each following week with the Wk_Num + 1 join, and reference the previous rows values

Comment: thank you for this. that last recursive join is what was giving me a headache. The only difference that I'm using for my case is for the base case, I simply do where Wk_Num = 1 (or which ever week happens to have the seed row needed)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SUM` `OVER` like this:

```
DECLARE @TempTable AS TABLE(T_In INT, T_Out INT, T_WeekNum INT)

INSERT INTO @TempTable VALUES (6, 0, 0)
INSERT INTO @TempTable VALUES (10, 12, 1)
INSERT INTO @TempTable VALUES (2, 6, 2)
INSERT INTO @TempTable VALUES (7, 5, 3)
INSERT INTO @TempTable VALUES (4, 0, 4)

SELECT
    SUM(T_In - T_Out) OVER(ORDER BY T_WeekNum ASC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) - T_In + T_Out AS T_Bop,
    SUM(T_In - T_Out) OVER(ORDER BY T_WeekNum ASC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS T_Eop,
    T_In,
    T_Out,
    T_WeekNum
FROM @TempTable
```

The calculation is the same for `BOP` and `EOP` but the values from the current row are subtracted from the `BOP` column to get the value from the last row.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. While I didn't give you the downvote (nor do I think you deserve a downvote...sorry, the internet is brutal sometimes), I can at least explain why I didn't choose your answer as THE answer. In your method, you are calculating the initial BOP/EOP out of the initial IN and OUT. You happen to have a sort of throw-a-way initial row identified as weekNum 0 in your temptable, which makes this example work out. But I need to be able to have a predefined, non-calulcated BOP/EOP to drive the next BOP/EOPs.

Comment: Ok, makes sense. Thanks for your comment.